# Paired t-test equivalent for comparing distributions (multiple Kolmogorov-Smirnov test)

Tags: r, distributions, t-test, multiple-comparisons, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am looking for an equivalent of a paired t-test but for distributions. Let me try to explain.

I am trying to test if a variable is selected randomly from the available pool of values or if there is a preference for high or low values.

I have 4000 days of records. For each day I have a known distribution of "available" values (in a form of a list of all "available" values) as well as a sample of "selected" values (from 1 to 10).

For each day I have calculated a mean of "selected" and "available" values and compared them using a paired t-test. The result is a significant difference in means, so far so good.

Now for each day (pair or "available" and "selected"), I would like to compare distributions instead of just means. Basically I would like to run something like 4000 independent Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests, one for each day, but then combine them into one synthetic result.
The only issue is that for each day the "available" distribution varies. One day values range from 0 to 1, another day from 0 to 100, and the same of course goes for "selected" values. Distribution is also skewed to the left.
All packages that I know of are of no use here as they allow to test multiple distributions but against **the same** reference distribution.

What I'm looking for is a distribution-comparing equivalent of paired t-test.

Does anyone know of a method to accomplish that, ideally with an R package to assist?

If not, can someone direct me to some reading on how to combine 4000 individual results of K-S tests into a single synthetic value?